# Upper and lower limit of function inequality

Tags: real-analysis

Let $f:(a,b)\to \mathbb{R}$ be a function and define upper and lower limits of function: $$\lim\limits_{x\to x_0} \sup f(x):=\inf_{r>0}\sup \{f(x): 0<|x-x_0|<r,x\in (a,b)\}$$ and $$\lim\limits_{x\to x_0} \inf f(x):=\sup_{r>0}\inf \{f(x): 0<|x-x_0|<r,x\in (a,b)\}.$$

How to show that $\lim\limits_{x\to x_0} \sup f(x)\geq \lim\limits_{x\to x_0} \inf f(x)$ by definition? I have tried but I stucked.

Would be thankful for your help!

Comment: Can you please explain what $\inf _{r \gt 0}$ means?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $L(r)=\inf_{x \in B(x_0,r)\setminus \{x_0\}} f(x), U(r)=\sup_{x \in B(x_0,r)\setminus \{x_0\}} f(x)$.

Note that $L$ is non increasing and $U$ is non decreasing and $L(r) \le U(r)$.

The following coarse schematic might help with the following inequalities: [image]

Suppose $0 < r \le r'$, then $L(r') \le L(r) \le U(r)$.
Suppose $0 < r \ge r'$, then $L(r') \le U(r') \le U(r)$.

In particular, we always have $L(r') \le U(r)$.

In particular, $\lim_{r' \to 0} L(r') = \sup_{r'> 0} L(r') \le U(r)$ and so
$\sup_{r'> 0} L(r') \le \inf_{r>0} U(r) = \lim_{r \to 0} U(r)$.

Comment: You wrote that $0<r\leq r'$ and conclude that $U(r')\leq U(r)$? But $U$ is nondecreasing.

Comment: Am I right or not? Since $U$ is nondecreasing and $r\leq r'$ we have $U(r)\leq U(r')$.

Comment: I made a mistake. the two lines need to be switched.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help! Let me ask you a question: Why $\lim_{r'\to 0}L(r')=\sup _{r'>0}L(r')$? Could you show why is this true?

Comment: $\lim \le \sup$ is always true. $L$ is non increasing, so the $\lim \ge \sup $ (otherwise a quick contradiction).

Comment: If $L$ is non increasing how it easily follows that $\lim \geq \sup$?

Comment: Suppose the limit is $l$ then $l \ge L(r)$ for any $r >0$ since $L$ is non increasing. Hence $l \ge \sup$.